# UWP: How to delay load DLLs in universal windows phone application?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10

I have developed a windows 10 universal application where the application startup time is considerably slow due to the initial dlls getting loaded. Even the [best practices from msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/best-practices-for-your-app-s-startup-performance) suggest to use delay loading the dlls but I could not find any example so far.

so, How to delay-load DLLs in universal windows phone application?

Also, in the same guide, it is mentioned that 'So, reference only assemblies that are necessary to the launch of your app in startup code so that the CLR doesn’t load unnecessary modules'... Are they referring to the same DLL delay load here?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that means use x:DeferLoadStrategy for custom controls (in this case they would be loading later)
Here is also nice link: [Optimizing your XAML app for performance (10 by 10)](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/10/07/optimizing-your-xaml-app-for-performance-10-by-10/)

Comment: Hi, I hope it is used for loading individual controls but in this case all the referenced dlls are getting loading during app launch.. so i want to delay the loading of dlls until it is actually required when using a particular dll in code. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I try to make an assumption. First you should add dll to your project. Then before dll is needed in code you can load it with:

    Assembly.Load(AssemblyName)